# Namespace not solving NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'login' not found. 'login' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: python, django

I have this error and don't know exactly the source of it, if it's an error in the apps urls, or in the projects urls.
The exact error is "NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'login' not found. 'login' is not a valid view function or pattern name."
The code is where the problem is:

```
<li class="nav-item">
  {% if not user.is_authenticated %}
    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'login' %}">Login</a>
  {% else %}
    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a>`
  {% endif %}
</li>
```

Here is my urls:
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from .forms import *

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name="index"),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('register/', views.UserSignupView.as_view(), name="register"),
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name="login.html", authentication_form=UserLoginForm)),
    path('logout/', views.logout_user, name="logout"),
]
```

And my projects urls:

from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('templates.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Disclaimer, I have tried adding the namespace, but this flags another issue, so wanted to see if there is any other issues with the code.

I have tried to see if the problem is in the projects urls, but to no success. Have tried to see if it's a form problem, but the form has no problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to name the URL properly, like:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('register/', views.UserSignupView.as_view(), name='register'),
    path(
        'login/',
        auth_views.LoginView.as_view(
            template_name='login.html', authentication_form=UserLoginForm
        ),
        name='login',
    ),
    path('logout/', views.logout_user, name='logout'),
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't write a name for "login" url. You must add `name="login"` to end of path.

```
path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name="login.html", authentication_form=UserLoginForm), name="login"),
```